# Does Jenkins "SCM Poll" while a job is running?

Tags: jenkins, cron

I have a Jenkins build triggered by a Perforce SCM Poll.

Does the poll continue to happen even if the Jenkins job is running? Or does it only poll between jobs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your question, I tried some google search but without any luck. Anyway, the best way to resolve an issue is EXPERIMENTING

#### STEP#01

Setup an testing job with `git` as source Code Management method.
[image]

#### STEP#02

In the `Build Triggers` section, set this job to `Poll SCM` every **2 minutes**.
[image]

#### STEP#03

Add an `Execute Shell` to set our testing job execute **2.5 minutes**.
[image]

> Now let's see what happened.

1. Firstly, last Poll started at **1:23:00 PM**

[image]

2. Secondly, latest build started on 1:24:00 PM and supposed to end at **1:26:00 PM**
   [image]
3. But you can see, Poll started again at **1:25:00 PM** regardless the build was still running.

[image]

> So "Does Jenkins “SCM Poll” while a job is running?"
> The answer is "YES"

Comment: This is causing multiple builds to stack up indefinitely. Any idea how to disable polling if that same project is currently building?

Comment: @JoshM. What we ended up doing is to move the poll to new independent job earlier in the pipeline and trigger the build job from it. For a git project, sha1 can be passed as parameter from poll job to the build job.

Comment: We ended up ditching polling and going with webhooks which is better in every regard.